# allocating new data to an already existent primary key

Tags: ms-access

I have a database of commands for a telephony switch, the relationships between tables are like so;
[image: relationships switch database]

The issue I am having is when I use a form I have designed;
[image: data form]

Used to view and enter data. I must allocate the data on the form to an overlay ID which is a primary key in overlays. I know what the form is trying to do when I enter new data and type in the relevant overlay ID, it is trying to add the overlay ID as a new overlay ID but the overlay ID already exists and therefore it cannot duplicate the ID.

I simply need to know how to I get my form to allow me to choose already existing overlay ID's (and the relevant linked overlay ID's) and allocate the information I am trying to add to it?

I have an understanding I can use a combo box but when I do this it changes the other records, when on the form, to no overlay ID and when you set the overlay ID in the combo box back to the original correct ID it just changes the rest of the records to that ID.

This is a university project and needs to have a minimum of 3 entities (tables) hence why there are some arguably unnecessary tables.

This could just be a silly question but I went into this project quite blind not really knowing much about access and now there is nobody to help!

Overlays are like the a section of the switch OS that allows you to carry out certain commands, so certain commands can be used in a certain overlay and that overlay will be linked with a select few overlays that can also carry out some of the same commands.

Comment: If you bind your form to the Overlay table and overlay ID is the PK, it should work fine

Comment: Tried this, it seems to be less problematic now but it's still not letting me add records to the other tables without trying to add a new record to overlayID. I don't want to add a new PK to overlay ID's but I want to put other records underneath the overlay PK. say for instance if you had a load of names in your DB in one table and you had a separate table of pay grades, I want to know how I can get my form to allow me to allocate an already existent "pay grade" to a new name.

Comment: Okay, Just got this working, your answer was a big help, thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific. Good job figuring it out though

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's not as complicated as I thought, essentially I was working off of an unbound form (or rather it was bound to a query containing all relevant fields).

If I wanted to add a record against a primary key of another table as described above, I needed to bind the form to the PlainTextFunction table, the table that contains the information to be allocated to the PK. This allows me to change the FK on the PTF table record which in turn links it to the overlay ID required without changing or adding a new PK. Doh!

So to clarify; to do this you want to edit the foreign key of the record that needs to be classified under the PK of the other table. Which will, in a sense, allocate that record being entered to the PK in the other table.